# Function in Where clause causes issues with query optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I inherited a stored procedure that I'm trying to get to run more efficiently.  Part of the procedure has this snippet:

```
select distinct t.claimid, max(rtwid)
from wkabrtw t
join #appealpendingdetails a on a.claimid = t.claimid
where convert(smalldatetime,t.statdt) <= a.appealrecddt
group by t.claimid
```

I know one issue is the `Convert()` function in the `Where` clause.  Does anyone know of another way to write that line without using a function in the Where clause?  The t.statdt value is a datetime.

Comment: The way to evaluate performance is to inspect the execution plan.

Comment: I understand that.  I'm asking if anyone knows how to rewrite the line with the Convert() function, basically an alternative to using a function in the Where clause.

Comment: Give us some more information, what datatype is t.statdt for example? Why is the convert there at all?

Comment: If it **must** be converted in order to compare it, the short answer is no. But does it need to be converted?

Comment: It's a datetime.  For now I'm just assuming the Convert is needed, but I'm not positive.  I just inherited this code and there are no comments.

Comment: Honestly - why does this need to be a set of 50 questions? There are TWO columns involved. What is the datatype of appealrecddt and why is it a different (presumably) datatype? You can safely remove DISTINCT - it does nothing useful.

Comment: If its a `datetime` then no convert is required. Like many things SQL, its often faster to just try something than to ask someone else whether it will work in advance.

Comment: All valid points.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't performance improvements in the where clause with Convert function.

Such as column retrieving, sql server will cast/convert your data into something "new", and then will use it to compare. Better would be not having to convert anything. Store your data as more compatible as possible.
Anyway, sql statements are fast and the convert function are compiled to be very fast.
You would have performance issues if you choose to open a Cursor every time to fetch rows, cast/convert and then compare.